# Unable to connect to teradata with Integrated Security authentication using JDBC connection string

Tags: jdbc, teradata

Unable to connect to teradata with Integrated Security authentication using JDBC connection string.
Unfortunately there isn't much help for teradata, but I have referred to SQL server and used the below connection string.

```
String Connurl="jdbc:teradata://hostname/database=xxxx,integratedSecurity=true";
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connurl);
```

I am getting below error. Not sure if I am missing something, can anyone throw me some light please?

> java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.10] [Error 1536] [SQLState HY000] Invalid connection parameter name integratedSecurity

Basically my intention is to connect to Teradata using windows authentication, instead of providing username and password.

Comment: Does teradata have such a connection property? The error suggests it doesn't. Why do you think `integratedSecurity=true` would work? Did you check the teradata documentation? Connection properties (except `user` and `password`) are driver-specific.

Comment: I don't think integratedSecurity is a known parameter for Teradata. Various database systems use different keys in the connection string for JDBC. There is no standard afaik.

Comment: The [documentation](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html) is your friend.

Comment: BTW, if you are looking for single signon, I think that's only supported with Kerberos.

Comment: @Andrew Sure, LDAP and Kerberos is an alternate option I have for SSO. But integrated security looked like a direct option for using Windows authentication, instead of me providing username and password.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. I can't find integratedSecurity parameter in Teradata documentation. But there is integratedSecurity option in TeradataSQL Assistant, which I am using on daily basis to connect to DB manually. So the confusion.

Comment: See [Encryption, Authentication, and Authorization](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABCGIDA): _"Single Sign On (SSO) is only supported with the Kerberos logon mechanism."_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for sharing. Its very helpful.